# Позиция кнопки в scroll view после Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Привет, после выполнения этого кода 
`var Fbutton = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("FButton"), transform.position, Quaternion.identity);` желательно чтобы кнопки растягивались по ширине, ну и не было расстояния между кнопками.  http://prntscr.com/goa2zt http://prntscr.com/goa3ep http://prntscr.com/goa3yj кто-то подскажет как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего такие штуки делать при помощи [Vertical Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html). Выставляете `Child Force Expend` для ширины и сбрасываете под высоту. Тогда кнопки будут растягиваться под ширину группы. При помощи `Padding` и `Spacing` настраиваете отступы от края в группе и между собой. Ну а дальше остается в коде добавлять ваши объекты в эту группу и они сами будут изменять размер под доступную область

Comment: спасибо) Я просто забыл указать что делаю еще SetParent(), после этого у меня сбивается scale (становится меньше). Указал в коде нормальный размер и все заработало.